# How to set load restrictor when using kustomize from kubectl?

Tags: kubectl, kustomize

I am trying to use kustomize from within kubectl. Specifically, I want to know the equivalent kubectl command for:

```
kustomize build --load_restrictor LoadRestrictionsNone config/overlays/dev_mutation | kubectl apply -f -
```

(kustomize properly runs this command and does what I expect)

I've tried this command:

```
$ kubectl apply -k config/overlays/dev_mutation --load_restrictor="LoadRestrictionsNone"
```

which complains that `load_restrictor` is deprecated and I should use `load-restrictor` instead.

```
W0712 07:58:16.811301 2407909 flags.go:39] load_restrictor is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use load-restrictor instead.
Error: unknown flag: --load_restrictor
```

So, I tried replacing with the non-deprecated flag:

```
kubectl apply -k config/overlays/dev_mutation --load-restrictor="LoadRestrictionsNone"
```

If I do this, kubectl complains that `--load-restrictor` is unknown:

```
Error: unknown flag: --load-restrictor
```

How do I properly pass the `load_restrictor`/`load-restrictor` flag to `kubectl apply -k`?

Output of `kubectl version`:

```
gatekeeper$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.2", GitCommit:"092fbfbf53427de67cac1e9fa54aaa09a28371d7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-16T12:59:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Common config across multiple environments and applications with Kustomize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65150509/common-config-across-multiple-environments-and-applications-with-kustomize)

Comment: @Pit No, I am specifically looking for the kubectl command equivalent.

Comment: I am not aware of any other usage of it apart from ```kubectl kustomize DIR with load-restrictor``` flag as seen in the [kubectl's official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest installing the `kustomize` binary directly, instead of relying on the bundled version in `kubectl` which would be outdated. More info here: [Install Kustomize](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/installation/kustomize/)

I do not think you can pass the `--load-restrictor` option to `kubectl apply -k` command. Instead, I can confirm that this works

```
kubectl kustomize --load-restrictor LoadRestrictionsNone <path_to_kustomization_dir>
```

You can use kustomize binary to achieve the same using

```
kustomize build --load-restrictor LoadRestrictionsNone <path_to_kustomization_dir>
```

#### Applying generated yaml

If you want to apply the generated output using kubectl, you can pipe this output like so

```
kubectl kustomize --load-restrictor LoadRestrictionsNone <path_to_kustomization_dir> | kubectl apply -f -
```

or

```
kustomize build --load-restrictor LoadRestrictionsNone <path_to_kustomization_dir> | kubectl apply -f -
```