# Handle "shared" resources with Kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

All namespaces in my cluster are supposed to trust the same root CA. I have a mono repo with all my Kustomize files, and I'm trying to avoid having to add the root CA certificate everywhere.

My idea was to go for something like that in my kustomization files:

```
# [project_name]/[namespace_name]/bases/project/kustomization.yml
configMapGenerator:
  - name: trusted-root-ca
    files:
      - ../../../../root-ca/root-ca.pem
```

So at least if I want to update the root CA, I do it in one place. This results to

```
file sources: [../../../../root-ca/root-ca.pem]: security; file 'root-ca/root-ca.pem' is not in or below [project_name]/[namespace_name]/bases/project/
```

So I guess this is not the way to go. (Reading from [Common config across multiple environments and applications with Kustomize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65150509/common-config-across-multiple-environments-and-applications-with-kustomize) I can see why it's behaving like that and disable that behavior seems to be a bad idea). I'm looking for a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a good place to use a [component](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/components.md). For example, if I have my files organized like this:

```
.
├── components
│   └── trusted-root-ca
│       ├── kustomization.yaml
│       └── root-ca.pem
└── projects
    ├── kustomization.yaml
    ├── project1
    │   ├── kustomization.yaml
    │   └── namespace.yaml
    └── project2
        ├── kustomization.yaml
        └── namespace.yaml
```

And in `components/trusted-root-ca/kustomization.yaml` I have:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component

configMapGenerator:
  - name: trusted-root-ca
    files:
      - root-ca.pem

generatorOptions:
  disableNameSuffixHash: true
```

Then in `projects/project1/kustomization.yaml` I can write:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: project1

components:
- ../../components/trusted-root-ca
resources:
- namespace.yaml
```

And similarly in `projects/project2/kustomization.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: project2

components:
- ../../components/trusted-root-ca
resources:
- namespace.yaml
```

And in `projects/kustomization.yaml` I have:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- project1
- project2
```

Then if, from the top directory, I run `kustomize build projects`, the output will look like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: project1
spec: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: project2
spec: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  root-ca.pem: |
    ...cert data here...
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: trusted-root-ca
  namespace: project1
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  root-ca.pem: |
    ...cert data here...
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: trusted-root-ca
  namespace: project2
```